# Why TextBox changed event triggering three times when type the value using korean keyboard?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am using the korean language in my pc. If i type the value in TexBox Control TextBoxChanged event triggered three times. First time i got the typed value, second time i got the empty value at last i got the typed value.

If anyone know the reason for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason is Korean IME will track key strokes and display the
>   intermediate character. So when we let richtextbox output its text in
>   TextChanged event, it will break IME's work
>
> This is indeed due to a defect in the RichTextBox that causes IME entry mode to exit each time a character is completed, due to sending a WM_IME_COMPOSITION windows message to IME that causes it to think IME was completed.  This is triggered when the Text property of the RichTextBox is retrieved. 
>   Here is a workaround, which overrides the RichTextBox window procedure to intercept and avoid this erroneous code path for Korean IME entry, and uses an internal value for Text to avoid calling the underlying control's property if IME is mid-composition, but still update after each character is entered.
>   Note that the class exposes a bool property called KoreanWorkaroundEnabled, which is true by default.  You can set this to false to revert the behavior to the default, which will be necessary if your text input language is Chinese or Japanese.  In those cases, this workaround will break the normal behavior.  You can use the InputLanguageChanged event on the host form to set the property according to the current entry language:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.InputLanguageChanged += Form1_InputLanguageChanged;
    }

    void Form1_InputLanguageChanged(object sender, InputLanguageChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.InputLanguage.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals("ko"))
            richTextBoxKorean1.KoreanWorkaroundEnabled = false;
        else
            richTextBoxKorean1.KoreanWorkaroundEnabled = true;
    }
```

> Here is the overridden RichTextBox class that implements the
>   workaround:

```
public class RichTextBoxKorean : RichTextBox 
{

    [DllImport("imm32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int ImmGetCompositionString(IntPtr hIMC, uint dwIndex, byte[] lpBuf, int dwBufLen);

    [DllImport("imm32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr ImmGetContext(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("imm32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr ImmReleaseContext(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr context);


    public enum WM_IME
    {
        GCS_RESULTSTR = 0x800,
        EM_STREAMOUT = 0x044A,
        WM_IME_COMPOSITION  =0x10F,
        WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION   =0x10E,     
        WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION     =0x10D
    }

    private bool skipImeComposition = false;
    private bool imeComposing = false;

    public bool KoreanWorkaroundEnabled = true;

    string _mText = "";

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (KoreanWorkaroundEnabled)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case (int)WM_IME.EM_STREAMOUT:
                    if (imeComposing)
                    {
                        skipImeComposition = true;
                    }
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;

                case (int)WM_IME.WM_IME_COMPOSITION:
                    if (m.LParam.ToInt32() == (int)WM_IME.GCS_RESULTSTR)
                    {
                        IntPtr hImm = ImmGetContext(this.Handle);
                        int dwSize = ImmGetCompositionString(hImm, (int)WM_IME.GCS_RESULTSTR, null, 0);
                        byte[] outstr = new byte[dwSize];
                        ImmGetCompositionString(hImm, (int)WM_IME.GCS_RESULTSTR, outstr, dwSize);
                        _mText += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(outstr).ToString();
                        ImmReleaseContext(this.Handle, hImm);
                    }
                    if (skipImeComposition)
                    {
                        skipImeComposition = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;

                case (int)WM_IME.WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION:
                    imeComposing = true;
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;

                case (int)WM_IME.WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION:
                    imeComposing = false;
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;

                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
            base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            if (!imeComposing)
            {
                _mText = base.Text;
                return base.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                return _mText;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
            _mText = value;
        }
    }
}
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cefa5376-7912-47f6-b86a-197a211c2b70/get-text-from-richtextbox-control-without-disturbing-ime-when-input-east-asian-language?forum=winforms